# Python exercise using try/except with continue

Tags: python, try-except, continue

I can't figure out why my code doesn't work properly here, it seems to exit the for loop after the **except: continue** line. What do I do to fix this? (the code executes but the output is always -1 no matter what list/letter combination is fed so nothing is ever being added to the sum_total variable)

```
sample_list = [
  'Black Mirror', 
  'Breaking Bad', #2
  'Stranger Things', #6
  'The Leftovers', #2
  'How I Met Your Mother' #7  4.25
]
letter = 'e'
def find_average_first_index(input_list, input_letter):
  sum_total = 0
  for i in input_list:
    try:
      sum_total += input_list.index(input_letter)
      print(sum_total)
    **except:
      continue**
        
  if sum_total == 0:
    return -1
  else:
    average_value = (sum_total / len(input_list))
    return average_value
```

Comment: Can you add the call of the function?

Comment: Without seeing the values being passed to your function, it's hard to explain. I assume the asterisks are there for highlighting purposes.

Comment: `except:  
continue` Is badly indented

Comment: Did you mean `i.index(input_letter)`? You are just checking if the letter is in ***the list*** each iteration, not in every string...

Comment: The stupid `except` hides the useful error message which would tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `index` on `input_list`. I think you might want to use it on `i`.

```
sum_total += i.index(input_letter)
```

When you call `index` method with an element not in the `list` it will raise `ValueError` Exception and your code will go to `except` block and because of the `continue` there, it will move to next iteration. And because you are using `index` method on input_list with `letter`, it will always raise ValueError in this code and that is the reason for the bug in your code.

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_index.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_index.asp

Answer (score 0):

Here's fixed code:

```
def find_average_first_index(input_list, input_letter):
sum_total = 0
for i in input_list:
    try:
        sum_total += i.index(input_letter)
        print(sum_total)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
        print(f"No {input_letter} in {i}")
        continue
    
if sum_total == 0:
    return -1
else:
    average_value = (sum_total / len(input_list))
    return average_value
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code need to change like this

```
sample_list = [
   'Black Mirror',
   'Breaking Bad', #2
   'Stranger Things', #6
   'The Leftovers', #2
   'How I Met Your Mother' #7  4.25
]

letter = 'e'

def find_average_first_index(input_list, input_letter):

   sum_total = 0
   for i in input_list:
       try:
           sum_total += input_list.index(input_letter)
           print(sum_total)
       except:
           continue
       if sum_total == 0:
           return -1
       else:
           average_value = (sum_total / len(input_list))
           return average_value

find_average_first_index(sample_list,letter)
```

errors:-

1. You need to add `try` and `except` like this (if your code pattern is wrong you can see error messages; see: https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-break-and-continue/)

   ```
   try:
     sum_total += input_list.index(input_letter)
     print(sum_total)
   except:
     continue
   ```
2. `find_average_first_index(sample_list,letter)`

   run the code you need call function. (ref: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp)

Comment: I tried to clean this up but there were several places where I had to guess, and several places where I simply could not guess what you really meant. Could you please still [edit] to clarify this?